# Compare and merge vector elements C++

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I have a (somewhat) basic question. I have a vector with string elements of the following type:

```
1 X 2
1 X 4
1 X 7
2 Y 1
2 Y 3
3 X 4
3 X 12
.....
etc
```

Now what I want to do is to merge the elements that have the same starting coefficient and append "00" until I have 6 integer elements after X,Y etc so my output would be:

```
1 X 2 4 7 00 00 00
2 Y 1 3 00 00 00 00 
3 X 4 12 00 00 00 00
.....
```

I've tried iterating over my vector and comparing my elements with find() and adding them to another vector but it doesn't work. I'm not super comfortable with vectors so any ideas would be appreciated! :)

Comment: *"but it doesn't work."* What does that mean? Also please show the code you tried so we can help you fix it

Comment: What if I have two elements `1 X 2` and `1 Y 2`. What would the result be? Also, are you familiar with a `std::map`?

Comment: Iterate over your strings. Construct a `std::istringstream`. Use `>>` to parse each field in the string.

Comment: I'd iterate over it first to get a structure like: `{{"1 X 2","1 X 4","1 X 7"},{"2 Y 1","1 Y 3"},{"3 X 4",3 X 12"}}`. You could do that with a vector of string vectors, or a map like AndyG suggested. Then turning `{"1 X 2","1 X 4","1 X 7"}` into `1 X 2 4 7 00 00 00` is just a matter of looping. Use an array with 5 elements (not 6 because your first element stays the same) all set to the string `"00"` so you have `{"12", "00", "00", "00", "00"}`. Then finally join it together using a space as the delimiter and append it to "3 X 4" (your first element) and add the result to your output vector.

Comment: @AndyG what I basically have in my vector are atoms and their coefficients, as well as the atoms they are bonded to (so if I have 1 X 2 it can technically be translated to atom 1 X bonded to atom 2 etc; it will be impossible to have both 1 X and 1 Y for example) sadly I am not familiar with map, I'm just a poor chemist :)

Comment: @JavaNewb. No problem. A map "maps" keys to values. In your case you could construct a map of coefficients to "values" (could be a `std::vector`, `std::array` or a custom container). You'll need to be able to "tokenize" the string to accomplish this (but I imagine you already have a way to do this). You may want to reconsider your current method of storage if this is the only task you need it for... I don't see how a pure string representation is particularly advantageous.

Comment: @Ultimater I'll try it and see how it goes, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @JavaNewb I think that an `std::multimap<string, string>` may suit your needs since you need to use multiple values per key.